# sharepoint 2013 workflow association not allowed

Tags: 2013, development

I am developing a SharePoint 2010 workflow in Visual Studio and all the time after deploy it I have to go in `Workflow settings` in the list and select `allow` radio button to the workflow associations.

How can I set the value `allow` as default before deploy?

Or maybe a PowerShell script to do it for me.

Comment: Use a feature receiver and do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a feature receiver and below code

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://siteurl");
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
// get the list where the workflow is associated            
SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];

// get the workflow assocation (check the index)           
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAssociation wrkflow = list.WorkflowAssociations[0];
wrkflow.Enabled = true;
list.UpdateWorkflowAssociation(wrkflow);
```